# Small issue in node js application

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

In my nodejs application I have route /login which uses sendFile to display my html file which takes name and password.In my server side app.js I wrote post call to take name and password.Now from my html Iam doing an ajax call to call the post call and if success I want to go to /admin page.For this I am thinking of to call in my rest call itself res.send().But Iam not aware how to send html file ..

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/home.html');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/login.html');
});

app.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/admin.html');
});

app.post('/verifylogin',function(req,res){
    var username = req.headers.uname;
    var password = req.headers.pwd;
    var uname = "admin";
    var pwd = "admin";
    var login = false;

    if(uname == username && pwd == password){
        console.log("success");
        login = true;
    } else {
        console.log("fail");
        login = false;
    }

    if(login == true){
        res.send();//how can I take to /admin here
    } else {
        res.send("Bad luck");
    }
});
```

html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function login(){
        var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
        var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;

        $.ajax({
            url : '/verifylogin',
            type : "POST",
            headers : {
                "uname":uname,
                "pwd" :pwd
            }
        });
        console.log("name",uname);
    }
 </script>

 <h1>Login</h1>
 <p>
     <label class="control-label">Username</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  id="uname"/>
 </p>
 <p>
     <label class="control-label">Password</label>
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwd"/><br/>
 </p>
 <p>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login()">Login</button>
 </p>
```

If login is success how can I route to /admin ..can someone help here!

Comment: You have a lack on theory.. You should use cookies to check if user is logged in. If he is at the login page and have login cookie you should redirect him to /admin, if not - show login view. When you make a post call, you save login to cookie and then answer with ok or ko if logged in. On front-end if you get ok you do the "window.reload()" for example..

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to be the subject of your problem, not the general area of technology.  Can you image if all node.js questions had a subject of "node.js question".  That type of subject is meaningless.  Tags already identify the question as node.js.  The subject should tell us what type of problem you have, not what runtime is being used.

Answer (score 1):

As @jfriend00 stated the browser doesn't redirect from an ajax call. So you can do 1 of the 2 options i'll show.

**1º Option:**

**Client**: Remove the ajax script and handle the call through html form.

Add a form to your html page:

```
<form method="post" action="/verifylogin">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"  name="uname"/>
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Server**:

Use the `redirect` method instead of `send` to redirect to the specified URL.

```
if (login == true) {
    res.redirect('/admin');
}
```

**2º Option:** Send the page as content to the ajax call and redirect the page to it.

**Client**:

On your ajax post add the success function:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/verifylogin',
    type : "POST",
    headers : {
        "uname":uname,
        "pwd" :pwd
    },
    success: function(data) {
        window.location = data;
    }
});
```

**Server**:

```
if(login == true) {
    res.contentType('application/json');
    var data = JSON.stringify('your_url') // im not sure if you can use relative path here
    res.header('Content-Length', data.length);
    res.end(data);
}
```

Comment: This are my server side logs..Getiing 302

success
POST /verifylogin 302 21.890 ms - 28

Comment: I can see the html as response in XHR..But looks like it didnt redirected..what is the issue here @Jackowski

Comment: How can we redirect in client side

Comment: @user7350714 can you check if my edits solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't do anything useful to do `res.redirect()` on an ajax call.  The browser won't go to that page.  So, the OP should either take an ajax result and redirect itself with `window.location` as you show as an option or a form post done solely by the browser (and not via ajax) can be redirected from the server with `res.redirect()`.  Your answer shows both.  The OP needs to pick one of the other depending upon whether the /logic post is done via ajax or via a browser post.